# How can I change the "sent via" link on tweets?

Tags: twitter

I was wondering if you could change the text and link of the "sent via" information on each tweet? The default value is "sent via web" and then if you use 3rd party application is could say "sent via TweetDeck", etc. But I know that this can be set and changed but I don't know how?

Thanks!

Comment: Is this in a 3rd party app your writing, or on twitter itself?

Comment: A 3rd party app that I'm writing.

Answer (score 4):

The "sent via" value can not be changed on a per-tweet basis.

Twitter applications that use the API are required to register with Twitter.  The registration contains the application name.  Anything posted to Twitter from that application will use that name.  This value can not be overridden.  If the owner of the application changes the application name, then you would see new values in the "via" field.

This can not be changed by the end user, and you can not set it in the code of your application.

Comment: I'm sorry but you seem to have the wrong answer:

http://socialmediatoday.com/sarah-hartshorn/148714/how-brand-your-tweets-twitter?utm_source=smt_newsletter&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=newsletter

Comment: The article you point to is selling a product/service.  I assure you that they are accomplishing the Tweet branding in exactly the same way that I have described,

Comment: You're wrong. I follow someone on Twitter who changes her "via" daily, to say things like "via your mother's house." There ianal a way to do it, apparently.

Comment: They are, in all likelihood, a developer who has written their own application and are changing the name of their application.  If you write your own Twitter application and register it with Twitter, then you could do this.